# List of all supported languages and their file extensions for .gitignore and gist

Tags: gitignore, github-api, gist

Is it possible to get list of all github supported languages for gist files and projects (.gitignore)? List of .gitignore supported languages displayed on the image below on the left side. And list of all gist languages is on the right side.

Also it would be greatfull to get list of appropriate extensions to these languages.

[image: List of .gitignore and gist languages]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Apparently, there seem to be lists of all supported things?!

Comment: @phresnel, I mean list in JSON format. For example:
`[{"language":"ActionScript"}, {"language":"C"}, {"language":"C#"}], {"language":"C++"}], ..]`

Comment: I see. What have you found out so far or tried to do?

Comment: http://developer.github.com/v3/gitignore/ for the gitignore templates. There's no equivalent for languages yet.